# Evaluate a function with 3 different variables for the whole list of each variable

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, expression-manipulation, map, mapthread

I have a function with 3 variables
`f[t1,t2,t3]`

Each function has a list of values

```
list(t1)=[{5},{2}...]
list(t2)=[{5},{4}...]
list(t3)=[{2},{4}...]
```

I need to evaluate the function at all the values

I was trying to use map unsuccessfully

Comment: Take a look at MapThread.

Comment: `list1 = {{5}, {2}};
list2 = {{5}, {4}};
list3 = {{2}, {4}};
MapThread[f, Flatten /@ {list1, list2, list3}]`

Comment: Do you mean "evaluate the function for all combinations of the list-values" ? Then you should do `list1 = {{5}, {2}}; list2 = {{5}, {4}}; list3 = {{2}, {4}}; 
Outer[f, list1, list2, list3] // Flatten `  which yields `{f[5, 5, 2], f[5, 5, 4], f[5, 4, 2], f[5, 4, 4], f[2, 5, 2], 
 f[2, 5, 4], f[2, 4, 2], f[2, 4, 4]} `

Comment: Not clear how many functions do you have: in the first sentence you write "I have a function with 3 variables", in the second sentence you write "Each function has a list of values"